# ucanaccess SQL Exception: invalid cursor state: identified cursor is not open

Tags: java, eclipse, ms-access, sqlexception, ucanaccess

I am a little bit confused,

I am trying to **insert multiple rows to MS Access database** from a java program using **ucanaccess** Java library.

I don't understand why the above (check title) **SQL Exception** is thrown when calling the **2nd insertRow()** method?

The Exception is NOT thrown either by calling **con.setAutoCommit(false);** & **con.commit();** methods or by re-executing the SQL query using the command **rs = st.executeQuery(sql);**. I also do not understand why the problem is solved by doing one of the above. **What changes?**

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class db1 {

    private Connection con;
    protected  Statement st;
    protected ResultSet rs;

    public db1() {
        connect();
    }

    public void connect() {

        try {
            String driver = "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);

            String db = "jdbc:odbc:Database1";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection
          ("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\Κώστας\\Desktop\\Database1.accdb");
            st = con.createStatement
          (ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,
          ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT)

          // con.setAutoCommit(false);

          String sql = "select * from TableA";  
          rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

          rs.insertRow();

          // rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

          rs.insertRow(); // HERE the SQL Exception is thrown.

          // con.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new db1();  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UCanAccess has some known issues with updatable ResultSets because it uses triggers on the HSQLDB backing tables to push the changes to the Access database file. A side effect of those triggers is that they can leave the HSQLDB ResultSet in an invalid state.

The problem you are experiencing may not manifest itself with `con.setAutoCommit(false);` because the triggers probably don't flush the changes to the Access database until the JDBC transaction is committed.